# How to Protect Your Rest API accessed via URL

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, rest, http

How can we prevent people from accessing our data stored on our API via our URL.  Currently anyone can go to our domain.io/users and see our users data.

Does anyone have any recommendations or solutions on how to password protect this? Should it be through htaccess? Or maybe a token system, or HTTP Auth?
Our site was built with Deployd and allows users to register/log in & post.
(Sorry if this has been asked before.)
Thanks so much!  Lanie

Comment: `Should it be through htaccess? Or maybe a token system, or HTTP Auth?` Yes.

Comment: @Vld  All of the above, or one in particular?  Thanks!